# SQL Statement JOIN for students and class

Tags: php, sql, database

I am trying to create a page where students can view the homework set by teacher for their classes. With the query I have now, it is not giving me any errors, but it's not returning the right classes. Instead it appears to show the latest that have been added. Here is my SQL statement.

What I need is a statement which selects from each class that the student that is logged in is associated with.

```
$id= $_SESSION['id'];

 mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM class INNER JOIN student_class ON class.class_id=student_class.class_ID INNER JOIN student ON student.ID= student_class.class_ID WHERE tbluser_ID='$id' ");
```

Here is how I want the information to be displayed

```
        <table width='80%' border=0>
        <tr bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Class Name</td>
            <td>Manage </td>
        </tr>
        <?php 
        //while($res = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
        while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {         
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$res['class_id']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$res['classname']."</td>";
```

And here is my database
[image: database]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The join condition that brings in table `student` does not seem right.

I think that this:

```
ON student.ID = student_class.class_ID
```

Should be:

```
ON student.ID = student_class.student_ID
```

New query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM class c 
INNER JOIN student_class sc ON sc.class_id = c.class_id
INNER JOIN student s ON s.id = sc.student_id
WHERE s.tbluser_ID = :id
```

Side note:

- you *do* want to use prepared statements instead of concatenating variable into your query string; you can have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/10676716) for the whys and hows
- table aliases usually make queries easier to read and maintain
- generally you want to avoid `SELECT *`; it is better to enumerate (and alias if needed) the columns that you want your query to return

Comment: @omar Please note that GMB has used PDO's prepared statement functionality here. You should too in your code.